# Selecting anchors within div by div id

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

New to JS, just dipping in to solve a problem (I bet everyone says that!). I need to write a script to select an anchor and insert an `<img>`.
There are several `<a>`'s within a div that has an id of `_nwa_social_logins`. I need to add an `img` tag to one of those. I'm not sure of the best way of doing this.

It's a captive portal page served up by a product we use, and the bit I'm interested in looks like this:

```html
<div id="_nwa_social_logins">
  <a class="btn btn-facebook" href="<url>/guest/social-media.php?oauth_init=1&amp;oauth=facebook" title="">
    <i class="icon-facebook"></i> Facebook
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-linkedin" href="https://<url>/guest/social-media.php?oauth_init=1&amp;oauth=linkedin" title="">
    <i class="icon-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-google" href="https://<url>/guest/social-media.php?oauth_init=1&amp;oauth=google" title="">
    <i class="icon-google"></i> Google
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-twitter" href="https://<url>/guest/social-media.php?oauth_init=1&amp;oauth=twitter" title="">
    <i class="icon-twitter"></i> Twitter
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-github" href="https://<url>/guest/social-media.php?oauth_init=1&amp;oauth=azure" title=""><img src="images/icon-microsoft.png" align="middle">Microsoft Azure AD
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-github" href="https://<url>/guest/social-media.php?oauth_init=1&amp;oauth=amazon" title="">Amazon</a>
</div>
```

So far I have

`let items = document.querySelector('#_nwa_social_logins a');`

To be honest I don't know how to even check if that has selected anything.

I need to select the Amazon anchor and set an `<img>` for the button. If the selection above gives me a list of `<a>`s (objects?) can I loop through them and look for one that has an href value that ends with 'amazon'?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {

        let links = document.querySelectorAll('#_nwa_social_logins a');
        links.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.getAttribute("href").toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('amazon') >= 0)
                link.innerHTML = '<img src="someimage">';
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is brilliant - but I've just realised I have misunderstood this. Actually what I want to do is insert an "img src" within that <a>, and remove "Amazon", so the end result should be: 

  <a class="btn btn-github" href="https://<url>/guest/social-media.php?oauth_init=1&amp;oauth=amazon" title=""><img src='someimage'></a>

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. Just one more wrinkle I'd like to solve if you don't mind - the button image is now showing, but there must be a background color set as there is a large black border around it. When I try "link.style.backgroundColour = 'transparent';" it has a really strange effect - all of the buttons change to my new button! It seems that changing the style or class attribute has this effect! Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: You have mistyped, change backgroundColour to  backgroundColor

Comment: And if you want to remove border, you can do by this ```link.style.border = '0px';```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227658/discussion-between-guy-goodrick-and-vahid).